# error : identifier “atomicExch” is undefined under visual studio 2012 and cuda 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda, atomic

I'm trying to compile a CUDA code under Visual Studio 2012 with CUDA 7.5 SDK but I'm getting an error

> "error : identifier "atomicExch" is undefined".

So I tried to get some information from CUDA SDK Samples and some forums but I'm still unable to solve the problem.

Any suggestions or can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Post your code... there are no clairvoyants here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I finally solved it by adding the following to my code:

```
// Compile kernel code for Compute 2.0 and above only

#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200

    // Device funtions on the GPU

#endif
```

Comment: But CUDA 7.5 only supports compute 2.0 and above. There is no way of compiling compute 1.x code with that toolchain.

Comment: well somehow i got it to compile after i changed the code as above.

Comment: I think you're confusing an actual compile problem with an intellisense error.  The message you've shown: "error : identifier "atomicExch" is undefined", is likely originating from intellisense.  You can generally safely ignore intellisense output if an actual build of your code does not yield any errors.